# Rails NoMethodError: Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, nomethoderror

I have created a model 'MyModel' and related view, controller and migration for DB. Now when I am trying to add some data to it from rails console I get following error.

```
myrailsapp>> m = MyModel.new()
(pry) output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'mymodel' for #<MyModel:0x000000009d863>>
```

Please help.

**Migration**

```
class CreateMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mymodels do |t|
      t.belongs_to :vendor, index: true
      t.string :name, uniq: true, index: true
      t.string :type
      t.boolean :audio
      t.boolean :video
      t.boolean :discontinued
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**MyModel**

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor

  TYPES = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C'
  ]
  FEATURES = ['Audio', 'Video', 'Discontinued'].freeze
end
```

**mymodels**

```
create_table "my_models", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "vendor_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "type"
  t.boolean  "audio"
  t.boolean  "video"
  t.boolean  "discontinued"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "recorders", ["vendor_id"], name: "index_recorders_on_vendor_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Could you add your model ?

Comment: Added details for MyModel

Comment: Can you get a better stack trace than that? Might help if you install the better_errors gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the actual issue causing the error, but you appear to have named your table wrong:

`MyModel` should have a `my_models` table, not `mymodels`

CamelCase converts to lower case with underscores (snake_case).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a single line in your model

```
     class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
         self.table_name = "mymodels"
         belongs_to :vendor

         TYPES = [
          'A',
          'B',
          'C'
          ]
         FEATURES = ['Audio', 'Video', 'Discontinued'].freeze
     end
```

Thats all

Comment: Do you mean that I should remove all other contents inside MyModel ? And just place single line as you wrote ? And after making that change should I re-migrate or what ?

Comment: No just add    self.table_name = "mymodels"  top of your model

Comment: I added the line as you suggested but still no difference, same error.

Comment: Give me the exact error , I tried for you in my rails app it works